# Protractor 5.3.0 incompatible with firefox52 and IE11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, firefox, protractor, e2e-testing

The versions of the relevant modules:

Selenium-Webdriver: 3.6.0
Protractor: 5.3.0
Firefox: 52.7.2 (32-bit)
IE11

My protractor scripts work smoothly with chrome 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit).

The protractor.conf.js:

```
    exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.
    suites: {
        spec: ['spec/full/example_spec.js']
    },

    multiCapabilities: [
        // {
        //     browserName: 'chrome',
        //     chromeOptions: {
        //         args: ['disable-infobars']
        //     }
        // },
        {
            'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        },
        // { browserName: 'firefox' }
    ],

    maxSessions: 1,
}
```

Is it a bug of the protractor 5.3.0?

Comment: Update the question with the binary versioning info.

Comment: @DebanjanB how could I get the binary versioning info?

Comment: I meant Selenium, ChromeDriver/IEDriverServer & Chrome/IE versions :)

Comment: @DebanjanB I can only find the version of Selenium-webdriver, and have added it to the post